# Deleting and adding specific row/ column in SAS output

Tags: sas, format, output

I have the following data

```
DATA HAVE;
input year dz $8. area;
cards;
2000 stroke 08
2000 stroke 06
2000 stroke 06
;
run;
```

After using proc freq

```
proc freq data=have;
table area*dz/ list nocum ;
run;
```

I get the below output

[image]

In this output

1. I want to delete the 'dz', what can I do to delete this column?
2. I want a row in the end that gives 'total', what can I do to get a 'total' row?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want the output to be a SAS table or just a print statement ?

Comment: @Kermit preferably a SAS table. Thanks!

Comment: Why did you include DZ in the TABLES statement if you don't want its value in the output?

Comment: Why would you want a dataset that includes the individual observations and the sum of those values in the same variable?  That will be very hard to work with, you will constantly have to exclude the extra observation to do any analysis of the variable.

Comment: Should `dz` be simply `stroke` ? Is there an issue with the `input` statement ?

Answer (score 1):

There must be a better way of doing this, but the following code creates the desired table:

```
data have;
input year dz $8. area;
cards;
2000 stroke 08
2000 stroke 06
2000 stroke 06
;
run;

ods output List=list;
proc freq data=have;
table area*dz / list;
run;

data stage1;
    set list(keep= area frequency percent CumFrequency CumPercent) end=eof;
    area_char = put(area,best.-l); /* Convert it to char to add the Total row */
    if eof then do;
        call symputx("cumFreq", cumfrequency);
        call symputx("cumPerc", cumpercent);
    end;
    drop area;
run;

data want;
    retain area frequency percent; /* Put the variables in the desired order */
    set stage1(rename=(area_char=area) drop=cumfrequency cumpercent) end=eof;
    output;
    if eof then do; /* Manually create the Total row */
        area = "Total";
        Frequency = &cumfreq.;
        Percent = &cumperc.;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

Output (`want` table):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should subset your data with a where clause and use a title statement if a important partitioning variable is to be removed from output.  If you didn't subset how would your audience know if a count contained say episodes of `stroke` and `ministroke` if `ministroke` was also in the data.

Compute the frequencies with `freq` and use a reporting procedure (`print`, `report`, `tababulate`) that summarizes to show a total line.

Example:

```
data have;
input year dz $ area;
cards;
2000 stroke 08
2000 stroke 06
2000 stroke 06
;

proc freq noprint data=have;
  where dz = 'stroke';
  table area / out=freqs;
run;

title 'Stroke dz';
title2 'print';

proc print data=freqs noobs label;
  var area;
  sum count percent;
run;

title2 'report';
proc report data=freqs;
  columns area count percent;
  define area / display;
  define count / analysis;
  rbreak after / summarize;
run;

title2 'tabulate';
proc tabulate data=freqs;
  class area;
  var count percent;
  table area all, count percent;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing the need for subsetting. The original data I am using has already been subsetted for a specific disease in that variable. @Tom and that is the reason there is nothing much I can do to change the variable from dz to stroke in the input statement.

Comment: You can also use `BY dz` and procedure will add `dz=stroke` to the title area.  So if you have a different dz value in the future you don't have to change a `title` statement.  `BY dz` will also make it clear if the data has values you might not be expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your valuable responses. The following code gives me the desired output in a concise way

```
proc freq data=HAVE;
  tables area / list nocum out=a;
run; 


proc sql;
    create table b as
    select * from a
union 
select
           'Total' as area,
           sum(count) as count,
                  sum(percent) as percent
    FROM a
;
quit;

proc print data=b; run;
```

[image]